# Multiple upload using Laravel Storage

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-storage

I was try to upload multiple files using Storage so here's my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $gallery  = new Gallery();
    $gallery->name = $request->name;
    $gallery->description = $request->description;
    $gallery->save();

    $path = 'public'.'/'.str_slug($request->name);
    Storage::makeDirectory(str_slug($request->name));

    $image = new Image();
    if ( is_array($request->images)) {
        foreach ($request->images as $file) {
            $image->gallery_id = $gallery->id;
            $image->name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->extension = $file->extension();
            $image->save();
            Storage::putFileAs($path, $file);
        }
    } else {
            $image->gallery_id = $gallery->id;
            $image->name = $request->images->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->save();
    }
}
```

and I already setup my form like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="images" class="col-md-2 control-label">Images</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" id="images[]" multiple>
    </div>
</div>
```

it give me an errors like this:

> "Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter::putFileAs(), 2 passed in E:\laragon\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager.php on line 343 and at least 3 expected ◀"

so the problem is it the way I check that it has multiple file using is_array is right? and the second what can cause this problems?

Comment: `putFileAs` expects 3 arguments and you are passing 2, Check out the  [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files)

Comment: @Ying do you want to upload images to public folder or storage folder? Please confirm then I will add my answer below.

Comment: public folder, i try to put the third argument but it seem i do it wrongly.

Comment: If you are using Image Intervention to save the Image why would you use Storage? Why would you `return back()` within `foreach` ?

Comment: lol, yeah you right, i forgot to move it when copy paste it from single images.

Comment: @linktoahref where are they using `intervention`?

Comment: @lagbox `$image = new Image();` was present in the code so I assumed the OP might be using Intervention Image package

Comment: no i'm not using interevention at all. i actually confuse about using Storage or just using ->store.

Comment: Image is not from interevntion it was my Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the 3rd argument to the `putFileAs` method

```
if( is_array($request->images)){
    foreach ($request->images as $file) {
        $image = new Image();
        $image->gallery_id = $gallery->id;
        $image->name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->extension = $file->extension();
        $image->size = 555;
        $image->save();

        // Or any custom name as the third argument
        Storage::putFileAs($path, $file, $file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
} else {
        $image = new Image();
        $image->gallery_id = $gallery->id;
        $image->name = $request->images->getClientOriginalName();;
        $image->save();

        // Or any custom name as the third argument
        Storage::putFileAs($path, $request->images, $request->images->getClientOriginalName());
}
return back();
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files)

Comment: it work but it give me only just 1 files in database.

Comment: @Ying Sorry, I instantiated the Image outside the loop, Please check the updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can use below example. I think this will help you to solve your problem

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $gallery  = new Gallery();
    $gallery->name = $request->name;
    $gallery->description = $request->description;
    $gallery->save();

    $path = '/images/'.str_slug($request->name);

    if( is_array($request->images)){
        foreach ($request->images as $file){
            $image = new Image();
            $image->gallery_id = $gallery->id;
            $image->name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->extension = $file->extension();
            $image->size = 555;
            $image->save();
            $file->move(public_path($path, $image->name);
        }
    }else{
        $image = new Image();
        $image->gallery_id = $gallery->id;
        $image->name = $request->images->getClientOriginalName();;
        $image->save();
        $file->move(public_path($slug, $image->name);
    }
    return back();
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is the different between using Storage and just using move? i thought move just ordinary php function right?

Comment: You are using Storage class which it seems no need of this here, because Laravel provide File class object when uploading any image. And it also provides us all file functions.. and one more thing, you want to upload images inside `public` directory not in `storage` directory. So if you will use Storage class then you have to add additional code to move files `public` directory.

Comment: @Ying one more thing, if you will use `Storage::putFileAs($path, $file);
` then your files will move to your `storage` directory.  but by using `$file->move(public_path($path, $image->name);` you can upload file in anywhere like `public`, `storage` etc directories.. It provides us flexibility to move file where we want to upload.

Comment: yes u right, but i just make sure i can work with it. since after this i think i will use the other extention like amazon s3. and i want to make a private file which i think only using Storage that can.

Comment: If you want to use amazon S3 then you can use this package `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0` . It will help you upload files on S3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clear. You are trying to call the function "putFileAs" using 2 parameters, when she needs at least 3.
Just take a look in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.html#method_putFileAs)

So

Comment: yes linktoahref make me clear how to do it. but now the problem is it just give me 1 file in my database.

Comment: The documentation is totally useless actually, as it just shows the exact same information as the code itself, without explaing what $option does or how to use it